# Unexpected result with Numpy ctypes data_as pointer arrays

Tags: python, numpy, pointers, ctypes

I am getting an unexpected result with two Numpy arrays when I represent them as Ctypes pointers. I have created a minimal example that reproduces the problem I am running into:

```
import numpy as np
from ctypes import c_float, POINTER

c_float_p = POINTER(c_float)

a = np.array([1], dtype=c_float).ctypes.data_as(c_float_p)
b = np.array([2], dtype=c_float).ctypes.data_as(c_float_p)

print('a: {}, b: {}'.format(a.contents, b.contents))
```

When I run this I get the following output:

```
a: c_float(2.0), b: c_float(2.0)
```

Clearly the contents of the first array have been overridden with the contents of the second. Hence, it seems that the two pointers point to the same location. How can I avoid this from happening?

Note: I am using Python 3.6, Numpy 1.15.4.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out the above example runs as expected when I updated Numpy to 1.16.0.